# On first touch one time small lag on android unity2D platformer

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch

My 2D platformer for android works perfectly after build, except that when I touch the screen for the first time an one time small lag occurs. After that the app works perfectly.

I tried to find a solution for the problem but I had no luck. I think that the EventSystem is not called on start but I don't want to guess. Did have anyone a similar or the same problem?

Here is the code, UI script which is used. In the profiler this script causes the problem.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject menu;
    public GameObject options;
    public GameObject pause;
    public Animator animatorMain;
    public Animator animatorOptions;
    public Animator animatorPause;
    public bool hide;
    public bool show;

        public void UIDefaults()
        {
            menu = GameObject.Find("MainMenu");
            options = GameObject.Find("optionsMenu");
            pause = GameObject.Find("pauseMenu");

            animatorMain = menu.GetComponent<Animator>();
            animatorOptions = options.GetComponent<Animator>();
            animatorPause = pause.GetComponent<Animator>();

            hide = true;
            show = false;
        }

        /* --- MAIN MENU START --- */
        public void OpenMainMenu()
        {
            UIDefaults();
            animatorOptions.SetBool("OptionsBool", hide);
            StartCoroutine("WaitMainMenu");
        }

        // line 28. Coroutine
        IEnumerator WaitMainMenu()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.15f); // wait for Options menu animation to end.
            SetMainMenuActive();
        }

        // line 35. function to Start the Main menu animation.
        void SetMainMenuActive()
        {
            UIDefaults();
            menu.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
            options.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
            pause.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;

            animatorMain.SetBool("MainBool", show);
            animatorOptions.SetBool("StartOptions", show);
            animatorOptions.SetBool("OptionsBool", show);
        }
        /* --- MAIN MENU END --- */

        /* --- OPTIONS MENU START --- */
        public void OpenSettings()
        {
            UIDefaults();
            animatorMain.SetBool("MainBool", hide);
            StartCoroutine("WaitOptions");
        }

        // line 66. Coroutine
        IEnumerator WaitOptions()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.15f); // wait for Main menu animation to end.
            SetOptionsActive();
        }

        // line 73. function to Start the Options menu animation. 
        void SetOptionsActive()
        {
            UIDefaults();
            menu.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
            options.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
            pause.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;

            animatorOptions.SetBool("StartOptions", hide);
        }
}
```

I would like to get rid of the first touch lag.

Comment: Are you trying to load a different scene after the touch ? Or it is happening in the same scene ?

Comment: No, I'm not. It happens in the same scene. This occures after I start the game and I'm in the main menu. A small lag happens, one time, when I touch the screen for the first time and after that the lag disappears. I found a developer with a similar problem. Here's the [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/957256/why-does-eventsystem-lag-on-first-touch.html)

Comment: Sounds like a performance spike; if you haven't already I would attach the profiler, instructions for that are [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html) and see exactly what's causing the problem. You may discover it's coming from engine code you can't change, in which case you should file a bug report. The workaround in the link you provided sounds promising, but fwiw I've never seen that issue with my Android app, so I might suggest trying a different Unity version or a different Android device to see if the problem might be specific to one of those things.

Comment: @silencewebber thax for the help. I found the problem. It is the c# script when it is first time initiated. How can I cache or preload the script before the first frame? I think the issue is with the coroutines and this script will be needed all the time 'cause this is the UI script. I added the script code to the original question.